# How should I structure my API or Schema based on certain requirements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections in my mongodb database

1. Comment
2. Movies

comment has a field 'movie-id' which refers to the id of movie the comment belongs to but Movies collection does not have any field referring to Comment collection.

Now if I want to ask for a single movie by id and display all the comments based on that particular movie , should I make two API calls or should I add a field to Movies collection to refer to that particular comment id. The other option would be to call from comment based on movie_id (and not movie) and populate by movie but what if some movie have no comment then this would backfire ?

How to figure it out ?

To clear this even more

Here is Comment data :-

```
"_id": "5a9427648b0beebeb69579cc",
"name": "Andrea Le",
"email": "andrea_le@fakegmail.com",
"movie_id": "573a1390f29313caabcd418c",
"text": "Rem officiis eaque repellendus amet eos doloribus. Porro dolor voluptatum voluptates neque culpa molestias. Voluptate unde nulla temporibus ullam.",
"date": "2012-03-26T23:20:16.000Z"
```

And the movie data :-

```
 "imdb": {
                "rating": 7.4
            },
 "_id": "573a1390f29313caabcd42e8",
 "poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3NjE5NzYtYTYyNS00MDVmLWIwYjgtMmYwYWIxZDYyNzU2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzQzNzQxNzI@._V1_SY1000_SX677_AL_.jpg",
 "title": "The Great Train Robbery",
 "year": 1903
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to fetch the data multiple time then it would be best to just include comment inside the same collection. You don't have to normalize data if the comments are not used in other parts but only in a movie page.

Comment: I found out about virtual in mongoose, I guess that can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are two different things. How you model your domain and how you expose it(presentation). They are very similar concepts that developers normally confuse and merge as a single thing...from my point of view mistakenly.

First, I think you should design your model(I suggest using a DDD approach), separated from your representation classes. Actually I'd suggest you to have inputs and outputs for you API. So I see this:

- MovieInput(api)
- MovieOutput(api)
- Movie(for you business logic, what you save to database. You could even aggregate a anti-corruption layer here to make it db-agnostic, but that may be too much )

From the previous exercise, you will identify if comments should be in a different collection or not. Take into account that one of the many benefits(or differences) of using MongoDB is that you work with documents. This doesn't mean you cannot work with different collections, which are related. You can, but MongoDB is not really designed for that. So in this case I suggest you to have comments inside the movie collection. Unless you expect to have a huge amount of comments, in which case you may consider take it out.

About normalisation, being totally honest now a days, with microservices, noSql, etc. you should be comfortable with no normalised data and design your system accordingly.

Regarding the API. That will depend on your design on how it's expected to be used.
The best practice says that you have(and what I suggest in this case)

- POST /../movie - Creation. Takes a MovieInput and return a MovieOutput
- PUT  /../movie/{id} - Update. Takes a MovieInput and return a MovieOutput.This should be idempotent and should be actually a replacement. So in this case you upload everything, comments too. If you want to partially update the resource, better use patch
- DELETE /.../movie/{id} - Delete a movie with all the comments
- POST /.../movie/{id}/comment - Create a comment for that movie
- PUT /.../movie/{id}/comment/{id} - Replace a comment for that movie(idempotent)
- DELETE /.../movie/{id}/comment/{id} - Delete a comment with all the comments

I omitted GETs, etc. But I think it's pretty obvious. All this is from my point of view and experience. There are plenty of other successful approaches ;)

Comment: But to add comment field to movie I have to check for each movie's comment and then if present I have to add it to movie collection,  how should I be doing it, instead can I just look for comment and single movie and pass both the results to response ?

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied with the answers above and it seemed a lot of work and hassle which is not meant for clever developers. We look for solution that requires less work and clever code.

The best way which I found out is to use virtuals in Mongoose Schema where you can define your own virtual field (maybe a reference to other model) which is not seen by the database but you can still have it in your response. It may also be called as reverse populate. First get to know about populate in mongoose and then go with virtuals.

To read more about mongoose virtuals : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html

Hope this will be helpful